# Javascript - How do I pick up which element fired an event

Tags: javascript, events

Using the sample code from W3schools I am trying to set up a single event handler that will fire when any of multiple 'input' elements in a form are changed.

What I want is to receive the `<input name=xxxx>` name parameter
As I understand it, p1 and p2 should contain the event and the name of the `<input name=xxxx>` field that fired the event.  Instead I get a reference error, "p1 is not defined" from the event handler.  On search I have found many convoluted solutions to this question, some of which I don't understand, but none that actually solve my problem.  What am I doing wrong?

```js
function field_check(event) {
  var the_input = event.target.id;

  alert("field_check: event was: " + event + "\nand the entry field was: " + the_input);
}

document.getElementById("add_data").addEventListener("change", field_check);
```

```css
input {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

input:focus {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<form name=add_data id=add_data>
  <input type="text" class="ship" name="fname" id="fname" autofocus><br \>
  <input type="text" class="ship" name="lname" id="lname" required><br />
  <input type="text" class="ship" name="addr1" id="addr1"><br />
  <input type="text" class="ship" name="addr2" id="addr2"><br />
  <input type="text" class="ship" name="city" id="city"><br />
  <input type="text" class="ship" name="p_code" id="p_code">
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) I made you

Answer (score 1):

You mean to do

```
var s = document.getElementById("add_data");
s.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  field_check(event, event.target.name);
});
```

or even simpler

```
document.getElementById("add_data").addEventListener("change", field_check);
```

and have

```
function field_check(event) {
  console.log(event.target.name);
}
```

```js
function field_check(event) {
  console.log(event.target.name);
}

document.getElementById("add_data").addEventListener("change", field_check);
```

```css
input {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

input:focus {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<form name=add_data id=add_data>
  <input type="text" class="ship" name="fname" id="fname" autofocus><br \>
  <input type="text" class="ship" name="lname" id="lname" required><br />
  <input type="text" class="ship" name="addr1" id="addr1"><br />
  <input type="text" class="ship" name="addr2" id="addr2"><br />
  <input type="text" class="ship" name="city" id="city"><br />
  <input type="text" class="ship" name="p_code" id="p_code">
</form>
```

Comment: First, thank you for the very prompt answer.  Unfortunately this leads into the same problem that prompted a previous question - only alternate inputs fire the event.  I was able to demonstarte that the problem befoer was interactin between the CSS :focus style for the input fields but have you any idea what is happening this time?

Comment: Please update the snippet in the question with the relevant HTML in a [mcve]

Comment: the css input {
         background-color: lightblue;
         font-size: 15px;
         padding: 3px;
         margin-left: 30px;
        }

input[type=text]:focus {
         background-color: white;
         padding: 3px;
         font-size: 15px;
        }

and the event handler is as you suggested document.getElementById("add_data").addEventListener("change",field_check);  The event only fires every second 'input' field. When it does works properly when it doesn't style is not applied either.

Comment: Pls update the question as I have requested

Comment: Sorry, I realized what you asked for when I logged on today.  The minimal code is too long to put here so I have loaded it at  https://pastebin.com/BfuRXRqP  When you enter any field in the form, you should get a yellow background when the field has focus.  Enter anything and tab to the next input field.  You should get a pop up that names the field you just entered.  Alternate input fields will NOT pop up and the background will remain yellow after you exit to the next field.  I tested on Fierefox 93.0 on Fedora.

Comment: Some additional information that might be useful: if you exit the input fields using <tab> it behaves as described, but if you hit <enter> the event will fire on all fields but you then have to hit <tab> to get to the next field.  If you back up and enter more data into an input field that didn't fire, then it will fire on exit and the even/odd sequence resets.  Same happens if you use the mouse to enter the input field - if you fill the form using the mouse to position each entry field then they all fire properly.   But most people move between fields using <tab>!

Comment: I updated your snippet. It is certainly not a lot of code. I will look in one hour

Comment: @John I have tested my code in Chrome and Firefox. I think your issue was using alert.

Comment: THANK YOU!  That seems to have fixed it although I must confess I have no idea why "alert" should affect anything.  The script I was working on had several alerts, some debug and some required by the context.  I'll have to eliminate those but your suggestion makes the whole thing function as expected.  Again, thanks; as you might have infered I don't have a lt of experience with Javascript.   ... John

Comment: An alert will block the interface and possibly interfere with the script that is running next. Timing issue